# oData EndPoint: Does it affect the SQL query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, odata, odata-v4

I’ve been using OData for my apis.

While I generally like what is has to offer, it only uses the data Post my query, which forces me to to construct all the relationships ahead of time.

Does an oData EndPoint with EntityFramework pass my oData parameters to be execute pre my SQL query?

Right now if I plan to possibly use oData Syntaxes like $Expand, I have to use EF Include ahead of time.  Once again, the issue being that EF must build all of the potential relationships that I may use $Expand with...even if I don’t $expand anything.

Another example is if I am to use the $top(100) syntax.  Say I had 10000 results, EF will download all 10000 from the DB, and then OData will select the Top 100.

Would an oData endpoint inject itself between EF and the DB and only select 100 results from the DB in this case?

Comment: It sounds like you have implemented your controllers incorrectly! Please post examples of the queries and your controller implementation for the associated methods.

Answer (score 0):

In general OData and EF go hand in hand, OData translates the incoming HTTP request into a [Linq-to-Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities#:%7E:text=%20The%20following%20is%20the%20process%20for%20creating,query%20results%20back%20to%20the%20client.%20More) expression that EF then translates to a SQL expression.

## tl;dr

All of your comments and observations point to incorrect implementation within your controller, it sounds suspiciously as if you have followed a *Repository Pattern* based example instead of an EF based examples.

> Does an oData EndPoint with EntityFramework pass my oData parameters to be execute pre my SQL query?

That is exactly what the OData framework was designed to enable, but there is 1 caveat, you must configure your controllers in a way that the parameters can be passed through.

There are two mechanisms that allow this to happen, the first is that your controller needs to return an `IQueryable<T>` result (or you must pass an `IQueryable<T>` to one of the negotiated response handlers). The other is that you must not apply your own filter expressions that might contradict the parameters, otherwise you may result in no records being returned.

The following is an example of the two standard `Get` endpoints on an OData controller that will return a *Vehicle* query that will allow the `$expand`,`$select` and `$filter` expressions to be passed through:

```
[ODataRoute]
[HttpGet]
[OData.EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Vehicle> queryOptions)
{
    return Ok(db.Vehicles);
}

[ODataRoute]
[HttpGet]
[OData.EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromOdataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<Vehicle> queryOptions)
{
    return SingleResultAction(db.Vehicles.Where(x => x.Id == key));
}
```

If I call this with the following query options:

```
$filter=Make eq Holden and Model eq Commodore&$orderby=Year desc
```

then that will translate into a SQL query similar to this:
*(SELECT * would be expanded in full)*

```
DECLARE @make varchar(20) = 'Holden';
DECLARE @model varchar(20) = 'Commodore';

SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle
WHERE Make = @make
  AND Model = @model
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

*Yes the parameters will be properly parameterised as well!*

This simple controller will also pass through the `$expand` request and automatically join the necessary tables, there is no need for us to know or think about the potential *includes* up front at all.

In fact, if I add `$skip=5` and `$top=2` those clauses will also be applied directly to the SQL statement, and at most only 2 rows will be returned from the database.

---

There are two common scenarios where all this auto-magical query translation and pass through mumbo jumbo gets broken.

1. In the controller method, (for either of the collection or item) you do not return an `IQueryable` result, or you have otherwise executed the query and resolved it to an `IEnumerable` and then you have returned that, perhaps by casting it back to an `IQueryable`.

   - This tends to happen because when we start out we tend follow simple non EF based OData examples, they usually follow a repository pattern because it is simple to explain the model, example data and implementation in a single page of code.

   > Public Service Announcement : Do not try to use a Repository Pattern to wrap an EF model and context, almost all the benefits from EF will be lost. EF is a Unit of work pattern, OData is designed to work with it directly.

   The following controller implementation will NOT pass through the query options to the database, `$top`,`$skip`,`$filter`,`$select`,`$orderby` will still be applied, if it can, but only after retrieving *all* the records into memory first:

   ```
   return Ok(db.Vehicles.ToList());
   ```

   - `$expand` will not be applied, or rather it will result in `NULL` related records.
2. The other common issue is after *Actions* where a data record (or records) have been processed if we want to support the entire range of query options automatically, we again need to make sure we return an `IQueryable` expression that queries from the `DbContext`. If the expression is `IQueryable`, but is only querying against what is already in memory, then `$expand` and `$filter` for instance can only be applied to that data which is already loaded.

   - `SingleResultAction` is a good helper method for returning an `IQueryable` that has been scoped toa single item, but it will still allow the full range of *QueryOptions* to be applied.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to a world of pain - Odata is a great idea with a pretty bad implementation. But yes, it is a amazing - doing it myself.

> it only uses the data Post my query, which forces me to to construct all the 
>   relationships ahead of time.

If this asks what I think it does (your english is VERY unclear) then no, it does not - your fault is exposing ef objects directly. I have separate api objects and expose them using AutoMapper ProjectTo. Yes, I need to define relationships ahead of time, but not on ef level.

> I have to use EF Include ahead of time.

That is because you decide to. I acutally use, as I said, Automapper ProjectTo - and get the necessary expands from the OdataOptions SelectExpand information dynamically. No need to send the whole object graph to EF (which is what happens if you expand all possible expansions with includes), this will result in really bad performance. Just a page of programming to get the relevant includes.

> Would an oData endpoint inject itself between EF and the DB and only select 100 results 
>   from the DB in this case?

if it is programmed like that, yes. If someone challenged with LINQ programs it and packs ef in one of the ridiculous inefficient repository patterns that return IENumerable - then no, it will pull it possibly all. Been there seen that. But normally TOP(1) results in sql selecting only the first item.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Do you have a link to documentation for “ProjectTo”?  Regarding the OData end point, I was referring to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: Well, it is in one of the automapper libraries and automapper does have documentation.

Comment: I looked up automapping.  Seems no different then casting custom classes?  oData forces you to return the type you query :/

Comment: Ah, it acutally is VERY different if you bother writing an example. Among other things it allows centralization of mappings and reuse, which will come in VERY handy when doing cross controller operations (because you need one object from another controller)

Comment: Automapper is helpful if you are _NOT_ going to expose the EF entities directly through the OData model, however OData is already _mapping_ the request to EF and back, so for many applications automapper can actually involve more configuration and processing than if you just used EF to OData directly.